# list in reverse order python

Tags: python, list, reverse

How should I fix this code in order to get a list that is in the reverse order of sequence s?

```
def reverse(s):
    """Return a list that is the reverse of sequence s.

    >>> reverse([1,2,3])
    [3, 2, 1]
    """
    rs = []
    for element in s:
        rs = s + rs
    return rs
```

Comment: Quick fix: `rs = [element] + rs` -- but there are much more efficient ways to accomplish that

Comment: You can just use `rs = list(reversed([1,2,3]))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually do something like this (I'm assuming you cant use `reversed()`). This uses slicing notation to reverse a list.

```
def reverse(s): 
    return s[::-1]
```

I'm also assuming you need to wrap this in a function, you could just use the index notation on its own.

EDIT:

Here is a bit of an explanation of the `[::-1]` operation:

Slicing notation is of the format `[start_point:end_point:step]`

The `start_point` is not specified, this becomes the length of the list so the operation starts at the end.

The `end_point` is also not specified, this becomes `-1` so the operation will end at the start.

The `step` is `-1`, so it will iterate backwards in steps of 1 (i.e. every element of the list).

This will create a shallow copy of your original list. This means the list you pass into `reverse(s)` will remain the same.

Example for clarification:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = x[::-1]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> y
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

parameter passed to function is of type list.

```
def reverse(s):
    return s[::-1]
```